# Get all role assignments of an Azure AD Principal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, rbac

I have an Azure environment with multiple subscriptions and resources. My requirement is to have a functionality where if I pass a user name or SPN name, it gives me all azure resources (from management group to azure resource) where that user/spn has access to and what access it is (reader/ data reader etc).

Major catch is - I want PIM role assignments too. Is there a way to get it?

**Options explored**

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/role-assignments but this gives role assignments per scope. I want per user/spn
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-portal it does not cover PIM assignments and gives assignments per subscription only
3. Azure Resource Graph Explorer - this does not cover role assignments at all

Apart from iterating through 50 subscriptions, fetching role assignments per scope and then comparing object id, is there any better way?

Comment: Please edit your question and include what you have tried so far and the issues you're running into.

Comment: That is the catch, I cannot find anything. The API for RBAC (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/role-assignments) fetches role assignments per scope. I want per user. Apart from iterating through all the subscriptions and its resources and then matching the user/spn object id, I am at loss. Iterating through such huge data and then comparing object id, does not seem to be a good solution either. Hence the query.

Comment: Also tried this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-portal but sadly it does not give PIM assignments and then there is no GA api for PIM

Comment: Thanks. Please edit your question and include this information there only.

Answer (score 4):

@Gjoshevski has shared a useful command, but you still need to loop through each subscription to list the role assignments on each subscription (if you have more than one in your tenant).

The following Azure CLI commands will do the job.

```
spID='<ObjectID here>' # ObjectID of an Applicatin or Service Principal
$tenantId='<TenantID here>'
az login --tenant 'Your Tenant'
$sub_ids=$(az account list --query id -o tsv)

foreach ($sub_id in $sub_ids) {
    az account set --subscription $sub_id
    "Subscription Name: $(az account show --query name)"
    az role assignment list --all --assignee $spID --include-inherited --include-groups -o table
}
```

> Note that the above is PowerShell syntax but is using Aure CLI commands

Comment: `az account list --query id` does not return anything for me. Never worked with JMESPath queries but this does not look like one to me?

Comment: also this does not include PIM permissions as asked in the question, only currently assigned permissions

Comment: however it correctly returns permissions granted on resource groups and resources inside the subscription

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
az role assignment list --all --assignee <Pricipal_ID>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-role-assignment-list

Comment: this will only work for the subscription that the azcli is set on. see @rohancragg answer for proper usage of az cli

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below Powershell Script to get the role-assignement for a Service Principal Name in multiple Subscriptions.

```
Connect-AzAccount
$tenantID = "yourTenantID"
$spn = "serviceprincipalname"
$user= Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName $spn
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription -TenantId $tenantID
#$subscriptions.Id
foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
$set = Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription
$set
$roleassignment= Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $user.Id
$roleassignment
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Install the Azure Az PowerShell module | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-6.4.0)

Comment: Thanks for your help. There are two things here:
1. This works for SPN but for users it will not give me any PIM assignments
2. I was hoping to avoid doing the same thing of iterating through subscriptions

Comment: @codegal, 1.The above is for users SPN (service principal name). To do the same for SP(service principals) you can get the azuread application and match the object ID of the service principal for the application and get the PIM. 2.Unfortunately without iterations there is no direct way to get this.

Answer (score 0):

First define the object ID for the user you want to query. Connect to Graph and to Azure so all below commands work. Azure CLI must be installed on the system as well.

```
$PrincipalToQuery = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
Connect-Graph
Connect-AzAccount
```

Then you have to execute different code depending on what you want to query.

---

### Entra ID Roles (Active)

This command queries the user's currently active Entra ID roles, therefore including all statically assigned roles (in addition to roles currently enabled via PIM). The command already respects roles that come via role assignable groups. We add two additional properties to make the output more digestable.

```
$AzureRoles = Get-MgBetaRoleManagementDirectoryTransitiveRoleAssignment -All -Filter "principalId eq '$PrincipalToQuery'" -ConsistencyLevel eventual
$Output = foreach ($AzureRole in $AzureRoles) {
    $Principal = Get-MgBetaDirectoryObjectById -Ids $AzureRole.principalId
    $AzureRole | Add-Member -NotePropertyName PrincipalDisplayName -NotePropertyValue $Principal.AdditionalProperties.displayName
    $RoleDefinition = Get-MgBetaRoleManagementDirectoryRoleDefinition -UnifiedRoleDefinitionId $AzureRole.roleDefinitionId
    $AzureRole | Add-Member -NotePropertyName RoleDefinitionDisplayName -NotePropertyValue $RoleDefinition.DisplayName
    $AzureRole
}
$Output | Select-Object RoleDefinitionDisplayName,DirectoryScopeId,PrincipalDisplayName,PrincipalId,RoleDefinitionId,AppScopeId | Out-GridView
```

---

### Entra ID Roles - PIM (Eligible)

This command returns PIM enabled Entra ID roles only. It does not respect roles that come via role assignable groups, therefore we manually check for the principals' groups and build our result that way. Depending on if we query a user or a service principal, we need to either use `Get-MgBetaUserTransitiveMemberOf` or `Get-MgBetaServicePrincipalTransitiveMemberOf`. As above, we add two additional properties to make the output more digestable.

```
$EligibleAzureRolesUnfiltered = Get-MgBetaRoleManagementDirectoryRoleEligibilityScheduleInstance -All
$PrincipalToQueryTransitiveMemberOf = Get-MgBetaUserTransitiveMemberOf -All -UserId $PrincipalToQuery
# $PrincipalToQueryTransitiveMemberOf = Get-MgBetaServicePrincipalTransitiveMemberOf -All -ServicePrincipalId $PrincipalToQuery
$EligibleAzureRoles = $EligibleAzureRolesUnfiltered | Where-Object {($_.PrincipalId -eq $PrincipalToQuery) -or ($_.PrincipalId -in $PrincipalToQueryTransitiveMemberOf.Id)}
$Output = foreach ($EligibleAzureRole in $EligibleAzureRoles) {
    $Principal = Get-MgBetaDirectoryObjectById -Ids $EligibleAzureRole.principalId
    $EligibleAzureRole | Add-Member -NotePropertyName PrincipalDisplayName -NotePropertyValue $Principal.AdditionalProperties.displayName
    $RoleDefinition = Get-MgBetaRoleManagementDirectoryRoleDefinition -UnifiedRoleDefinitionId $EligibleAzureRole.roleDefinitionId
    $EligibleAzureRole | Add-Member -NotePropertyName RoleDefinitionDisplayName -NotePropertyValue $RoleDefinition.DisplayName
    $EligibleAzureRole
}
$Output | Select-Object RoleDefinitionDisplayName,DirectoryScopeId,PrincipalDisplayName,PrincipalId,RoleDefinitionId,AppScopeId | Out-GridView
```

---

### Azure Resources (Active)

This command queries the user's currently active Azure RBAC roles, therefore including all statically assigned roles (in addition to roles currently enabled via PIM). The command already respects roles that come via groups (they do not have to be role assignable). We include an additional query for which subscription the assignment is scoped to, because by default the subscription is only returned by its ID. The `Group-Object` is present to not list the same assignment multiple times (multiple subscriptions might inherit a role assignment from a `Management Group` higher up).

```
$Subscriptions = az account list --all | ConvertFrom-Json
$Output = foreach ($Subscription in $Subscriptions) {
    # use Azure CLI because the Powershell equivalent 'Get-AzRoleAssignment -ExpandPrincipalGroups' does not expand groups for service principals
    az role assignment list --all --assignee $PrincipalToQuery --include-groups --include-inherited --subscription $Subscription.id  | ConvertFrom-Json
}
$GroupedOutput = $Output | Group-Object Id | ForEach-Object {$_.Group | Select-Object -First 1}
$GroupedOutput | ForEach-Object {
    $IsInsideSubscription = ($_.scope.split('/'))[1] -eq 'subscriptions'
    if ($IsInsideSubscription) {
        $SubscriptionId = ($_.scope.split('/'))[2]
        $SubscriptionName = (Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId).Name
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName subscriptionName -NotePropertyValue $SubscriptionName
    }
}
$GroupedOutput | Select-Object roleDefinitionName,scope,subscriptionName,principalName,principalId,principalType | Out-GridView
```

---

### Azure Resources - PIM (Eligible)

This command returns PIM enabled Azure RBAC roles only. It does not respect roles that come via groups (they do not have to be role assignable), therefore we manually check for the principals' groups and build our result that way. Depending on if we query a user or a service principal, we need to either use `Get-MgBetaUserTransitiveMemberOf` or `Get-MgBetaServicePrincipalTransitiveMemberOf`. The properties that this command returns are readable enough, so we can just output its result. The `Group-Object` is present to not list the same assignment multiple times (multiple subscriptions might inherit a role assignment from a `Management Group` higher up).

```
$Subscriptions = az account list --all | ConvertFrom-Json
$PrincipalToQueryTransitiveMemberOf = Get-MgBetaUserTransitiveMemberOf -All -UserId $PrincipalToQuery
# $PrincipalToQueryTransitiveMemberOf = Get-MgBetaServicePrincipalTransitiveMemberOf -All -ServicePrincipalId $PrincipalToQuery
$Output = foreach ($Subscription in $Subscriptions) {
    $EligibleRBACRolesUnfiltered = Get-AzRoleEligibilityScheduleInstance -Scope "/subscriptions/$($Subscription.id)"
    $EligibleRBACRoles = $EligibleRBACRolesUnfiltered | Where-Object {($_.PrincipalId -eq $PrincipalToQuery) -or ($_.PrincipalId -in $PrincipalToQueryTransitiveMemberOf.Id)}
    $EligibleRBACRoles
}
$Output | Group-Object Id | ForEach-Object {$_.Group | Select-Object -First 1 RoleDefinitionDisplayName,ScopeDisplayName,PrincipalDisplayName,ScopeId,PrincipalId,RoleDefinitionId} | Out-GridView
```